# Javascript Math behavior

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

I don't get why javascript math lib calculate some wierd value when doing such simple math operation as 
(more examples in the fiddle)
http://jsfiddle.net/ye9amc2k/

```
16.99 + 21 = 37.99 ? not for javascript ! (37.989999999999995)
16.98 + 21 = 37.980000000000004 ...
```

Is it some rounding problem ? a type one  (int vs float) ? a browser one (i'm using chrome right now) ?

Comment: JavaScript numbers are always floating-point numbers.

Comment: This is how computer handle floating point numbers. It can become quite complex, but a computer cannot perfectly add two decimals and output the exact value without further arithmatic as some libraries like Math.js incorporate.